# New 4.0 API: WifiP2pManager... how to transmit data?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

In the new Ice Cream Sandwich SDK (4.0), there is a new section of the API for creating p2p connections over wifi.  There is plenty of information in the [WifiP2pManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pManager.html) class on how to connect and discover peers and peer groups, but very little detail on how to send data after a connection is established.  It says:

> The connection info WifiP2pInfo contains the address of the group
>   owner groupOwnerAddress and a flag isGroupOwner to indicate if the
>   current device is a p2p group owner. A p2p client can thus communicate
>   with the p2p group owner through a socket connection.

I don't have a ton of experience with creating socket connections.  **What would be needed for a peer to send data, and for a peer group owner to receive it, just from the WifiP2pInfo or connection methods?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being new, there isn't a lot of information on this, but the sample application from the android developers resources is a fantastic demo project that gave me everything I needed to know.

[WiFiDirectDemo Project](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/index.html)

With the `WiFiP2pInfo`, you can open a socket for data transmission.  It has an example for sending files in the demo.